# How do I make responsive bg heading tag?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have created a  tag with the background color.
The view is good in desktop but when changes to mobile the bg do not respond to the h3.

[Video](https://streamable.com/zci71u)

See the video attached please.

HTML code:

```
<div class="setup-box">
<div class="treeview-box-content">
<h3 class="setup-box-title">Windows</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS codes:

```
.treeview-ul {
margin-left: 1.5em;
text-align: left;
}

.treeview-box-content h4 {
font-size: 1.4em;
}

.treeview-box-content h4::after {
display: block;
z-index: 1;
margin: 0 auto;
content: ' ';
width: 100%;
height: .1em;
background: #b0e1f5;
margin-top: .7em;
}

.treeview-ul li {
line-height: 2.3;
font-size: 1.2em;
}

.setup-box {
width: 33.33%;
}

.setup-box-title {
background: #f3f1f1;
padding: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your pourcentage width set to 33%. Your bg text won't be able to grow to fill the text at that size.

You could use a media query to increase the width at smaller devices

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I fix that without media query?